# Trying to hide pseudo element on input focus through ~

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to hide parents pseudo element ::before hide on input focus and it **shouldn't** work on button focus. Currently it looks like this

```css
.parent::before{
  content: 'default';
}

.parent:focus-within::before{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text">
  <button>awd</button>
</div>
```

and it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to involve any js/jquery. Would be great if there any vanila css or atleast scss solution.
Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: Your code works for me as expected. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Jared I've updated my question, there was an answer to that question and then I updated the fiddle since I've had another problem with suggested :focus-within solution. The guy who answered my question here said, that he will update his answer but instead he just deleted it.

Comment: What you want cannot be achieved with your current HTML structure. You cannot exclude descendants from triggering `:focus-within`. Youw ill have to make the button a non-descendant of the element you check the focus-within on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with parent focus to control pseudo element, cause button and input both trigger focus on parent, you can't approve one and disapprove another. Instead, you can wrap input to do that.

```css
label::before{
  content: 'default';
}

label:focus-within::before{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label>
     <input type="text">
  </label>
  <button>awd</button>
</div>
```